Superset Athena failed to list tables
I'm setting up Superset connection to Athena.

I can connect to Athena.
I can list databases.
But I failed to list tables of databases

When I tried to list tables, an UI bug appears with non-sense information for debugging.
There was an error loading the tables: An error occurred
When listing the tables, seems super got some error (I have no idea to debug superset or get some kind of other log, new Superset user tbh).
Request URL:
https://superset/api/v1/database/1/tables/?q=(force:!f,schema_name:my_database)
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
422 Unprocessable Content

It looks like a permission issue, but I already set getTables permission:
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "glue:GetTable",
        "glue:GetTables",
        ...

    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:{id}}:catalog",
        "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:{id}:database/my_database",
        "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:{id}:table/my_database/*",
    ]
}   

Driver:
PyAthena[SQLAlchemy]>1.2.0, <2.0.0
I tried different driver version.
What maybe the reason? Or is there anyway to get relevant logs so that I can debug?
